# метод, возвращающий из json файла коллекцию

Tags: java, json, коллекции

Добрый день! Помогите написать метод,возвращающий  из json файла  `MAP` коллекцию {Id,Code}

```
"__type": "EnerSys.Energy.enARM.EnergyService.ArmEntity",
        "Values": [
          {
            "Id": 1001007032,
            "Value": 0.8711100,
            "ValueAbsPt": 7.8964090,
            "FactorId": 9,
            "EntityId": 32596,
            "CorrectionId": 0,
            "IsPending": false
          }
        ],
        "Id": 32596,
        "Code": "PEDINEC9",
        "Name": "Имя \u0026#8594; ОАО \"Саратовский нефтеперерабатывающий завод\" (PEDINEC9)"
      },
      {
        "__type": "EnerSys.Energy.enARM.EnergyService.ArmEntity",
        "Values": [
          {
            "Id": 1001006387,
            "Value": null,
            "ValueAbsPt": 0.0000000,
            "FactorId": 9,
            "EntityId": 41413,
            "CorrectionId": 0,
            "IsPending": false
          }
        ],
        "Id": 41413,
        "Code": "PEDINEC6",
        "Name": "Самарская энергосистема \u0026#8594; ЗАО \"Завод\" (PSANORS2)"
      },
      {
        "__type": "EnerSys.Energy.enARM.EnergyService.ArmEntity",
        "Values": [
          {
            "Id": 1001003349,
            "Value": null,
            "ValueAbsPt": 0.0000000,
            "FactorId": 9,
            "EntityId": 41415,
            "CorrectionId": 0,
            "IsPending": false
          }
        ],
        "Id": 41415,
        "Code": "VEDI",
        "Name": "Самарская энергосистема \u0026#8594; ЗАО \"Завод\"-\"Водозабор\" ()"
      },
      {
        "__type": "EnerSys.Energy.enARM.EnergyService.ArmEntity",
        "Values": [
          {
            "Id": 1001007074,
            "Value": null,
            "ValueAbsPt": 0.0000000,
            "FactorId": 9,
            "EntityId": 44914,
            "CorrectionId": 0,
            "IsPending": false
          }
        ],
        "Id": 44914,
        "Code": "PSANORA5",
        "Name": " \u0026#8594; ООО \" \"Pfdjl\" (PSANORA5)"
      }
    ],
    "CloseGateDateLocal": "\/Date(1505107800000)\/",
    "CloseGateDateMsk": "\/Date(1505107800000)\/",
    "IsCorrection": false
  }
```

}

Comment: Какой язык программирования?

Comment: java программирование

Comment: С чем у вас возникла проблема?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону `jackson` или `Gson` фрейморков

Comment: проблема как произвести поиск в этом файле,учитываю что "Id" должно быть обязательно с "Code" и добавить элементы в коллекцию